# Runtime error 1004 when using Cut and PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

I have to cut the contents from active cell for a specific range in sheet 1 and paste it into the active cell of that range in sheet 2. Cutting the specific range of contents is working fine, but in the paste options I am getting runtime error 1004 as application defined or object defined error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub sheet1_sheet2_copy_click()
  Sheets("sheet1").Activate
  ActiveCell.Resize(1, 26).Cut
  Sheets("sheet2").Activate
  ActiveCell.Resize(1, 26).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to resize? Do you just want the value of the cell there, or is the formatting important too?

Comment: Please next time use a title that relates to your specific problem, not a repetition of the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think using the active cell as a source and destination is rather unreliable, but if you change the paste line to `activesheet.paste` it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but you can try doing this:

```
Sub sheet1_sheet2_copy_click()

Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 26).Cut
Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 26).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Better yet, you can just do this:

```
Sub sheet1_sheet2_copy_click()
    Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 26).value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 26).Value
End Sub
```

In general, it is better to not use `.Activate` or `.Select`, but to instead explicitly define your references like I showed. Modify the `Paste:=` to whatever parameter you are trying to use for PasteSpecial.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel for more information on this command.

Comment: "but i used the record macro feature and that's what it said to do" - yes, but that is not necessarily the best way to do it...

Comment: The first code snippet is wrong. You can't `Cut` and then `PasteSpecial`... it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it looks like PasteSpecial only works if you use Copy instead of Cut, so you should modify your code this way:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 26).Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Activate
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 26).PasteSpecial
```

If you need to delete the data from sheet1, then do it after the PasteSpecial.